# Transforming an object with a javascript class

Tags: javascript

I’m transforming data I receive from an API.  The frontend requires some calculations to be displayed.

What is the proper way to handle the data transformation?

- Should I be defining a property to the object being passed? If so, why
- Is this a good use case to use setters and getters or would that be unnecessary?

---

```
const dogData = {
  dog_name: "filo",
  born_time: 1530983852,
  coat_color: "brown"
};

class Dog {
  constructor(data) {
    //do I need to set this.dog to the data object, what's the benefit of doing so?
    this.dog = data;

    this.name = this.dog.dog_name;
    // vs
    this.name = data.dog_name;

    //Should I use setters and getters?
    this.color = this.dog.coat_color;
    // vs
    this._color = this.dog.coat_color;

    this.age = this.calculateAge();
  }

  calculateAge() {
    return Date.now().getTime() - this.dog.born_time;
  }

  //Is this a good case where I  should using getters to access the properties or would that be superfluous?
  //should I be setting the properties with setters in this case?
  get color() {
    return this._color;
  }
}

const dog = new Dog(dogData)
```

Comment: `Dog.dog` doesn't make sense.  Just set the properties of the Dog (name & colour) and have the function for returning the age.  Anything else is overkill, *unless you can think of a reason to add them*.

Comment: I don't have control over the shape of the data I'm receiving.  This class is meant to make the data easier to consume by a react application.

Comment: Will Dog instances be immutable or will you allow properties like `born_time` to be changed after construction?

Comment: I can't think of a time I may need to mutate it.

Comment: If the OP never needs to mutate the initial configuration then an approach needs to work with getter functionality assigned/bound from within the constructor. There also is no need of any prototypal methods. But there should be exactly one local function that calculates the age for each `Dog` instance.

Comment: Till now none of the approaches prevents the mutation of a `Dog` instance. Was this a requirement or was it not?

Comment: I don't believe I'll need to prevent it from being mutated.

Comment: Ahh ..., got it, thanks. Shall I nevertheless throw in a possible read only approach?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt.  I appreciate the different approaches.

Comment: @MatthewMoran I wasn't suggesting that you change the shape of the incoming data.  I was referring to your `Dog` class.  Really, the answer depends on what you intend to do.  For example, if you're never going to require the age then don't make an age function.  However, in your class, holding the original dog variable as a property is not relevant.  Single instances of information are good, so `Dog.color` is good, but then also having `Dog.dog.color` is confusing.  Just make it easy to understand, from the point of view of someone who knows nothing about it.

Comment: @Archer sorry, I guess I'm not understanding where `Dog.dog` or `Dog.dog.color` is coming from.  I'm probably just missing something.

Comment: @MatthewMoran ... 1st line in your example's constructor ... `this.dog = data;` ... of course, a `dog` instance (and not `Dog`) then only refers via `dog.dog` to `dog.dog.coat_color` and not to `dog.dog.color`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your don't need to make a copy of data into your class.

You can assign the class fields directly (using [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) to be more readable).

```
const data = {
  dog_name: 'filo',
  born_time: 1530983852,
  coat_color: 'brown'
}

class Dog {
  // Directly assign values
  constructor({ dog_name, born_time, coat_color }) {
    this.name = dog_name
    this.bornAt = born_time
    this.color = coat_color
  }

  // Getter for computed properties
  get age() {
    return Date.now() - this.bornAt
  }
}

const dog = new Dog(data)
```

Getters are needed only for computed property (dynamic or formatted values).

Good exemple:

```
class Person {
  constructor({ firstname, lastname }) {
    this.firstname = firstname
    this.lastname = lastname
  }

  get fullname() {
    return `${this.firstname} ${this.lastname}`
  }
}
```

Comment: Updated, hope it helps. Thanks

Comment: Would it be wrong to have a function `getFullName` with a property defined in the constructor `this.fullName = this.getFullName(firstName, lastName)`?

Comment: Also, if there are many properties, 10+, is it still worth it to destructure?

Comment: It would not be wrong, but no need to define a function `getFullName`
You could just do `this.fullname = firstname + ' ' + lastname`.
Defining a function for a one-time usage into the constructor seems not very clean.

If there are many properties, always target the best readability.

Comment: Readability prevails regardless of the number of properties, if destructuring decreases readability it is not worth it, prefer `this.prop = data.prop`.

Comment: I should add to my first comment that if you prefer to assign the value in the constructor rather than using getters, your property will not be updated if it's 'dependencies' are updated. https://jsfiddle.net/5hae0pkd/

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Dog {
    constructor(data) {
        const {
            dog_name: name,
            born_time: age,
            coat_color: color
        } = data;
        Object.assign(this, {
            name,
            age,
            color
        });
    }
}

const dogData = {
    dog_name: "filo",
    born_time: 1530983852,
    coat_color: "brown"
};

const dog = new Dog(dogData);

console.log(dog.name);
```

Comment: `born_time` is fixed but `age` does vary over time, at least according to the OP's example.

Answer (score 0):

***Q***:

> Shall I nevertheless throw in a possible read only approach? – Peter Seliger

***A***:

> It wouldn't hurt. I appreciate the different approaches. – Matthew Moran

... here we go ...

```js
// module start ... e.g. file: "Dog.js"


// locally scoped helper function
function calculateAge(dateOfBirth) {
  return (Date.now() - dateOfBirth);
}

/*export default */class Dog {
  constructor(initialValue) {

    Object.defineProperties(this, {
      valueOf: { // just in order to hint what `initialValue` might still be good for.
        value: function () {
          return Object.assign({}, initialValue);
        }
      },
      name: {
        value: initialValue.dog_name,
        enumerable: true
      },
      color: {
        value: initialValue.coat_color,
        enumerable: true
      },
      age: {
        get() {
          return calculateAge(initialValue.born_time);
        },
        enumerable: true,
      }
    });
  }
}
// module end.


// test
const dogData = {
  dog_name: "filo",
  born_time: 1530983852,
  coat_color: "brown"
};

const dog = new Dog(dogData);

console.log('Object.keys(dog) : ', Object.keys(dog));
console.log('dog.valueOf() : ', dog.valueOf());

console.log('dog.age : ', dog.age);
console.log('dog.name : ', dog.name);
console.log('dog.color : ', dog.color);

console.log('(dog.age = 298146912) : ', (dog.age = 298146912) && dog.age);
console.log('(dog.name = "spot") : ', (dog.name = "spot") && dog.name);
console.log('(dog.color = "black") : ', (dog.color = "black") && dog.color);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```